# Part of the question disappeared and is not shown in revision history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revisions-list

In "[Select lines between “*line1*” and “*line2*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538307/select-lines-between-line1-and-line2)" post, part of the question has disappeared as reported by Dan Fego. He has even provided the original text of the question:

> How can I use grep to find text from line to line
>
> lets say I want to grep only "utility originally written" from the following text. How can i do that? Please help
>
> grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written for Unix.

How could this happen? Shouldn't the history of revisions be maintained and visible to SO users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only possible way this could *ever* happen is if the OP edited the question within the first 5 minutes that he posted it and removed that information, and that user just happened to notice the original question and copy-pasted the original text that was with it.

**Edit:** Like right now I'm editing to add this comment, but it won't show in the revision history...

I'm confused why the user didn't just edit that information back into the question.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. Have your upvote.

Comment: The timestamps of answer and question support this.